# Multiple Brokers Kafka 0.7

Tags: apache-kafka, broker

I am trying to start  multiple Brokers using Kafka 0.7.2. I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "kafka-acceptor" java.net.BindException:
Address already in use at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.run(SocketServer.scala:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I created two different config files for the two brokers, and run it with the command:

```
env JMX_PORT=9999   bin/kafka-server-start.sh  config/server.properties
env JMX_PORT=10000  bin/kafka-server-start.sh  config/server1.properties
```

I did the same with 0.8, and it worked fine. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I figured it out. The java sockets were open and hence the error.

Use the command to find the open java sockets and kill them

`netstat -a -n -p | grep java`

`kill -9 pid`

Comment: you're actually killing *some java application that runs on this socket* rather than freeing socket itself.

Answer (score 0):

Kill process using following command

```
   sudo fuser -k 2181/tcp
```